# I was emailed my password, want to confirm this is not secure

Tags: security, passwords, password-storage

I recently forgot my password for a site and went through their support process for resolving this. They emailed me my original password, in plaintext.

I sent them a scathing email stating that email is not a secure transmission protocol and that by sending me a plaintext version of my password they've indicated they're not storing a hashed version of my password. I went on to say that anyone with access to their database or who hacks their system would have access to the passwords.

Are these assertions correct?

Comment: yes all assertions are correct. Ideally they should send a link to reset password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assertions are correct.

While we can't be sure that they store the password in a plaintext format, it is clear that it is stored in a lossless form, and that it is possible for them (and potentially an attacker) to work out the plaintext password.

In any case, this is poor security.

One approach you, the user, can take to mitigate against such risks is to assign each site a unique random password. There are plenty of software tools that allow you to manage such passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If it was your original password then it's probably insecure. They might be encrypting it, but it's unlikely. And even if they were, encrypting passwords is only a bit better than saving them in plain text.

Comment: Also encrypting them does mean, that anyone from the site maintenance staff with access to the key can access the password database.